# Запись массива байт из файла в массив байт C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть текстовый файл в котором лежит большой массив байт.

Фрагмент файла:

ffffffff8ef213e4ffffffff83300000ffffffff8ef213d0ffffffff83533b68
ffffffff82d6d584ffffffff82d6d5680000000000000080ffffffff8ef213d0
ffffffff8ef21470ffffffff8ef2006000000000000004000000000000000000

Как записать побайтно весь этот буфер в массив байт, чтобы он выглядел так:

[ff ff ff ff 8e f2 13 ...]

Сделал пока вот так, но нельзя ли как-нибудь попроще?

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("buff.txt");
        string strbuff = sr.ReadToEnd();
        byte [] WorkBuff=new byte[strbuff.Length/2];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strbuff.Length;i+=2 )
        {
            string tempstring = strbuff.Substring(i, 2);
            WorkBuff[j] = (byte)Convert.ToSByte(tempstring , 16);
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: Что означает «чтобы выглядел»? Возможно, вам стоит прочитать [вот это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453060/10105).

Comment: если нужен массив байт, используйте BinaryReader. Или именно с ним и проблема? что уже пробовали делать? что из этого получилось и не получилось?

Comment: @VladD "Чтобы выглядел", для данного примера означает следующее: buff[0]=255, buff[1]=255, buff[2]=255, buff[3]=255, buff[4]=142, buff[5]=242 и т.д.

Comment: Вооот, так то лучше, теперь есть о чем говорить.

Comment: В файле HEX хранится в текстовом виде?

Comment: @rdorn да в текстовом

Comment: PS: не забывайте using, всё же к файлу обращаетесь. А то напомнило http://govnokod.ru/11621#comment151429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные хранятся в виде текста, то у вас в принципе все правильно, разве что можно преобразовывать сразу в Byte минуя SByte, и убрать лишний счетчик, хотя последнее вовсе не обязательно.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("buff.txt");
string strbuff = sr.ReadToEnd();
byte [] WorkBuff=new byte[strbuff.Length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < WorkBuff.Length; i++)
{
    string tempstring = strbuff.Substring(i*2, 2);
    WorkBuff[i] = Convert.ToByte(tempstring , 16);
}
```

Но лучше для передачи байтов использовать двоичный формат, тогда не придется городить огород из преобразований.

На EnSO советуют тоже самое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант с использованием [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/):

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
var bytes = text.Batch(2, pair => Convert.ToByte(new string(pair.ToArray()), 16)).ToArray();
```

Comment: пожалуй самый короткий вариант =) а с учетом граблей на х86, вероятно и более быстрый

Comment: @rdorn: А что за грабли на x86?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496918/198316 о, там много текста, если кратко, ошибка в JIT

Comment: @rdorn: Ага, понял. Спасибо!