# Алгоритм нахождения суммы степеней с уменьшающим основанием

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

### Задача

Решаю задачу на [Codewars](http://www.codewars.com): найти для следующей формулы `n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m` число *n*. Число *m* известно и передается в функцию `FindNb`. Если для переданного *m* не существует *n*, то ответ: -1. Например:

`FindNb(1071225) --> 45`

`FindNb(91716553919377) --> -1`

---

### Мое решение

Вот что сделал я:

```
public static long FindNb(long m)
{            
    long sum = 0;
    var nResult = 0;

    for (var i = 1; sum < m; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        nResult = i;
        for (var nMaybe = i; nMaybe > 0; nMaybe--)
        {
            sum += (long)Math.Pow(nMaybe, 3.0);
        }
    }
    if (sum != m)
    {
        nResult = -1;
    }

    return nResult;
}
```

---

### Вопрос

Мое решение **работает**, но сервис требует **оптимизировать** код (слишком долго выполняется). **Как это сделать?**

- сложность моего алгоритма получилась квадратичная (N^2). Не знаю как
  уменьшить ее.
- также думал может приведение `...(long)Math.Pow...` замедляет код, но
  поиск оптимизации по этой части тоже ничего не дал.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А если попробовать такой вариант, без вложенных циклов:

```
public static long FindNb1(long m)
{
    var i = 0;
    long sum = 0;
    while (sum < m)
    {
        i++;
        sum = sum + (long)Math.Pow(i, 3.0);
    }

    if(sum != m)
        return -1;

    return i;
}
```

Дело вот в чём: счёт идёт обратно, от единицы:

при n = 1 мы имеем формулу 1^3

при n = 2 мы имеем формулу 2^3 + 1^3

при n = 3 мы имеем формулу 3^3 + 2^3 + 1^3

и так далее. Накапливаем результат и на каждой итерации смотрим, не проскочили ли мы наш "эталон" в размере m. Если совпали с эталоном -- выводим счётчик цикла, если нет ("перескочили лишку") -- выводим -1.

У меня Stopwatch показывает на 100 повторах кода ускорение на порядок (исходный вариант, оптмизированный):

> ```
> 16386
> 1309
> ```

Comment: еще один порядок выиграть заменой `(long)Math.Pow(i, 3.0)` на `i * i * i`. Для малых целых степеней это работает значительно быстрее чем Math.Pow

Comment: @rdorn весьма хорошая мысль. Добавил в свой ответ такой вариант вместе с замерами скорости работы.

Answer (score 6):

Реализация идеи из ответа @Harry с формулой `S = [n(n+1)/2]^2` и квадратным корнем:

```
public static long FindNb(long m)
{
    var q = GetSqrtOrMinusOne(m);
    if (q == -1)
        return -1;
    // n(n+1)/2 = q <=> 4n^2 + 4n = 8q <=> 4n^2 + 4n + 1 = 8q + 1 <=> (2n + 1)^2 = 8q + 1
    var r = GetSqrtOrMinusOne(8 * q + 1); // r = 2n + 1
    if (r == -1)
        return -1;
    // 8q + 1 нечётно => r тоже нечётно, проверка не нужна
    return (r - 1) / 2;
}

static long GetSqrtOrMinusOne(long original)
{
    // для чисел в диапазоне long точности хватает, так что можно считать, что
    // ошибка не превосходит 0.5 => используем Math.Round.
    var q = (int)Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(original));
    return (q * q == original) ? q : -1;
}
```

Без циклов, O(1).

Answer (score 5):

Эта сумма равна (n*(n+1))^2/4.

Оцениваем, зная m, величину n как корень четвертной степени из 4m - с избытком. Дальше идем вниз, пока не получим совпадение или значение, явно меньшее m.

На C# не умею, на C++

```
long long FindNb(long long m)
{
    long long n = sqrt(sqrt(4*m))+1;
    for(;;--n)
    {
        long long sum = n*n*(n+1)*(n+1)/4;
        if (sum == m) return n;
        if (sum < m) return -1;
    }
}
```

Можно решать явно -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

тут нужно просто аккуратненько с корнями работать... Просто функции `sqrt()` я бы не очень доверял. Как минимум, найдя - перепроверить...

Дополнительная оптимизация - если `m` не точный квадрат - заведомо возвращаем -1.

Comment: А зачем оценивать-подбирать? уравнение прекрасно решается аналитически...

Comment: @Akina Ну да, но нас же интересуют целочисленные решения - так что все равно надо проверить. Всегда не доверяю корням из целых чисел и т.п. математике :)

Comment: *нас же интересуют целочисленные решения - так что все равно надо проверить* Ну и проверь обратным умножением... впрочем, с учётом того, что квадратный корень будет недлинным, достаточно выполнить проверку по последней цифре (предпоследняя просто обязана быть точной). Проверка (какую не используй) всё равно будет проще и дешевле, чем итеративный подбор.

Comment: @Akina Подбор будет никак не более 1-2 проб.

Comment: Блин, мы же в положительных целых работаем... тогда никакого подбора вообще не нужно, ибо `ROUND_DOWN(SQRT(x * (x + 1)) = x`.

Answer (score 4):

Если не использовать вариант `(n * (n + 1))^2 / 4`, то можно хотя бы не пересчитывать сумму для каждого `i`, а пользоваться суммой, полученной для `i - 1`:

```
public static long FindNb(long m)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (var i = 1; sum < m; i++)
    {
        sum += (long)Math.Pow(i, 3.0);
        if (sum == m)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

Если же вместо `Math.Pow(i, 3.0)` использовать просто `(long)(i * i) * i` или, если `i` гарантированно не будет превышать `1290` (что даёт сумму в 693 миллиарда), просто `i * i * i` (по предложению @rdorn), то работать будет ещё на порядок быстрее.

```
public static long FindNb(long m)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (var i = 1; sum < m; i++)
    {
        sum += (long)(i * i) * i;
        if (sum == m)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

Время работы для `m = 1071225` при 100 тысячах итераций:

```
Первоначальный вариант:   5110мс  
Math.Pow + сумма:          227мс
i * i * i + сумма:          19мс
Код @VladD:                 10мс
```

Время работы для `m` равного 100 миллиардам при 100 тысячах итераций:

```
Первоначальный вариант: >60000мс  
Math.Pow + сумма:         3950мс
i * i * i + сумма:         255мс
Код @VladD:                  4мс
```

Comment: i можно сразу выдать тип long, и ограничения не будет, но помнится у MS были какие-то проблемы с циклом [for и long на x86](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496918/198316), поэтому в данном случае я бы использовал while

Comment: @rdorn у меня вариант с `long i = 1` работает вдвое дольше `(long)(i * i) * i` (вчера тестировал и его), так что от него я отказался.