# Странные (лишние) инструкции после компиляции

Tags: c#, ассемблер, компиляция, компилятор

Игрался с замером скорости доступа к L1,L2,L3 кэша процессора средствами C# и случайно наткнулся на странное поведение компилятора (vs2017, х86, со включенной оптимизацией).

Приведу адаптированный кусок кода:

```
fixed (uint** array = new uint*[256])
{
    var p = array;
    uint iters = 1024;

    for (uint i = 0; i < iters; i++)
        p = (uint**)*p;
}
```

На выходе, цикл компилится абсолютно корректно:

```
011E0884  xor         edx,edx              //uint i = 0
011E0886  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax]  //p = (uint**)*p;
011E0888  inc         edx                  //i++
011E0889  cmp         edx,400h             //i < 1024 
011E088F  jb          011E0886
```

Но если изменить тип переменной `iters`, начинается магия:

```
fixed (uint** array = new uint*[256])
{
    var p = array;
    ulong iters = 1024; //  <---  отличие в этой строке

    for (uint i = 0; i < iters; i++)
        p = (uint**)*p;
}
```

В этом случае цикл компилится вот в такое:

```
00BA0888  xor         edi,edi              //uint i = 0
00BA088A  mov         esi,dword ptr [esi]  //p = (uint**)*p;
00BA088C  inc         edi                  //i++
00BA088D  xor         eax,eax      // Д
00BA088F  test        eax,eax      // И
00BA0891  ja          00BA089D     // Ч
00BA0893  jb          00BA088A     // Ь
00BA0895  cmp         edi,400h             //i < 1024 
00BA089B  jb          00BA088A
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему после изменения типа переменной `iters`, которая оптимизатором заменяется на константу, и которой по сути вообще нет, появляются лишние бестолковые инструкции?
2. В чем сакральный смысл помеченных четырех инструкций? Сперва обнуляем `eax`. Потом проверяем, а не ноль ли там случаем. И потом эти джампы, которые, насколько я понимаю, никогда не сработают... Это баг или фича?

Comment: А вы в записи `(uint**)*p;` с указателями ничего не напутали? Вообще удивительно, что даже со якобы включенной оптимизацией этот цикл не был выкинут целиком.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496918/198316 Почитайте, там в конце ответа отдельно про x86 и косяки в JIT-е, которые, видимо, так и не поправили

Comment: @VTT, ничего не напутали. И не с "якобы", а со включенной. Вопрос то в другом =)

Comment: @rdorn, там другой случай, поэтому не могу сделать такой же вывод относительно моего. В целом, я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что это косяк компилятора. Но вдруг кто-то скажет, что это магическое выравнивание, которое на самом деле здесь необходимо...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Похоже что оптимизатор не осилил убрать смесь  каста uint в ulong и последующего сравнения. Каст был из (edi) в (eax, edi), и выглядит как заполнение eax нулём (через xor).

```
00BA088C  inc         edi                  //i++

// каст uint i в ulong. Результат в паре eax, edi
00BA088D  xor         eax,eax     

// поразрядное сравнение двух ulong
// старший разряд 
00BA088F  test        eax,eax // вместо cmp eax, 0
00BA0891  ja          00BA089D     
00BA0893  jb          00BA088A     
// младший разряд
00BA0895  cmp         edi,400h    
00BA089B  jb          00BA088A
```

Т.е. вроде как оптимизатор мог догадаться, что верхний разряд можно не сравнивать, но не догадался. Оптимизатор x86 старый, не ждите от него слишком многого :)

Comment: Да, как же это гениально! Я настолько зациклился на мысли, что компилятор просто накосячил, добавив лишенные смысла инструкции, что не допер, что это под ними на самом деле подразумевалось сравнение старших разрядов...