# Почему foreach работает для массива намного быстрее, чем для IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, циклы, оптимизация, .net-5

Недавно рефаторил проект, делал универсальные методы, абстракции в аргументах вместо конкретных типов, и заметил, что производительность приложения незначительно упала. Начал копать, добрался до того, что виноват во всём цикл `foreach`.

Кажется, `foreach` оптимизирован для массива. Решил протестировать.

Вот 2 совершенно одинаковых метода, исходные данные - один и тот же массив. Разница только в сигнатуре.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = BenchmarkRunner.Run<ForeachBenchmarks>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class ForeachBenchmarks
{
    private readonly int[] _numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1000000).ToArray();
    public IEnumerable<int[]> Numbers { get { yield return _numbers; } }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Numbers))]
    public int SumArray(int[] numbers)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int n in numbers)
            sum += n;
        return sum;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(Numbers))]
    public int SumIEnumerable(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int n in numbers)
            sum += n;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

И правда оптимизирован:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1081 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU 2.40GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.301
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.7 (5.0.721.25508), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.7 (5.0.721.25508), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | numbers | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SumArray | Int32[1000000] | 468.9 us | 1.84 us | 1.44 us | - | - | - | - |
| SumIEnumerable | Int32[1000000] | 5,808.0 us | 44.16 us | 39.15 us | - | - | - | 32 B |

Объясните пожалуйста, почему `foreach` в 10 раз медленнее, если использовать интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` для массива, чем если использовать `T[]`?

**UPD:** Провел тесты для `List<int>` и для `ReadOnlySpan<int>`. Для списка `foreach` такой же по производительности, как для `IEnumerable<T>`, а для спана такой же как для массива.

Comment: Потому что больше кода генерируется? Дополнительные объекты, вызовы методов. А если явно известно что на входе массив, то используется оптимизированная версия с обращением по индексу https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAFgNwFgBQWoGYEBMcAwnAN5ZZzUL4CWAdgC5wDKArgLYCCATrwEMAngApGTANoBdOAy4AjAKa8AzgEoqNCphq644uCq5wAvHBgYde6gDMA9r0UCAxgAs4Y5rP0NZC5eqa1rpGnHBgZgyWwQgA7IZc0TQAvpRW1Hg+LBycSLgieQA84gB8fpxKqhrp5EF6BqGm5knW9o4u7p4svozllYE1MY0Rsi16UPGhY6mYyUA

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вон оно что. Черт, а посмотреть в рефлектор я и не догадался. Это всё объясняет, буду лепить перегрузки методов с дублированием кода теперь, чтобы там, где массив, генерилось меньше кода. :) Оформите ответом? Вдруг кому-то пригодится.

Comment: _Он как-то, получается, оптимизирован для массивов чтоли, или мне кажется?_ - именно так, если foreach применяется к массиву, msil соответствует обычному for

Comment: @Grundy Я не нашел ответа на свой вопрос "Почему foreach работает для массива намного быстрее, чем для IEnumerable?". Не считаю дубликатом, переоткрыл. Ссылка для истории, связанный вопрос: [Проход по массиву: прямой, обратный или итератор?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496858/373567)

Comment: @aepot, в ответе прямым текстом говорится, что для массива код foreach такой же, как и for - плюс приведены листинги msil и asm

Comment: @Grundy зато там ничего не сказано про foreach для IEnumerable. Там больше разбор foreach в сравнении с циклом for, а не с самим собой для разных типов коллекций.

Comment: В дотнете ещё столько возможностей для оптимизации. *Печально вздыхает*. Вот, например, в [IEnumerable.Count](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1314) проверяется тип и в случае `ICollection` сразу берётся значение свойства. Почему подобное не сделали для форыча? Открыли бы Мелкомягкие доступ к изменению компилятора, энтузиасты давно бы сделали такие оптимизации.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я думаю, что в при компиляции неизвестно какой тип у коллекции, поэтому генерится с итератором. С другой стороны могли бы проверку типа коллекции вынести в рантайм. Кода бы стало больше конечно, но мне кажется работало бы быстрее. Да и логично это. Я думаю для листа не оптимизировали только потому что не знают как бросить Collection was modified при работе через индексаторы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, *Открыли бы Мелкомягкие доступ к изменению компилятора, энтузиасты давно бы сделали такие оптимизации* — открыто же. Но нельзя просто так завязаться, например, на `IList`, потому что внутри может быть что угодно. '@aepot, при явном указании `IList` оптимизации все равно нет. Контракт `foreach` нельзя нарушать, я могу написать реализацию `IList`, которая будет бросать исключение при обращении к индексатору, но при этом нормально работать с `GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` и `foreach` должен работать!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: https://habr.com/p/493586/

Comment: @АндрейNOP - открыты исходники, но это не значит, что я могу изменить компилятор. Я не могу в своём проекте вмешаться в ход компиляции. Невозможно изменить код, генерируемый компилятором, невозможно создать собственную языковую конструкцию. У нас нет макросов (хотя в Microsoft работает специалисты, прекрасно знающие их реализацию). Дотнет сильно отстаёт по оптимизациям от JVM и именно поэтому часто сливает Жаве. Хоть обнадёживает, что в последнее время ими серьёзно занялись.

Comment: @Alexander, ну вы всегда можете предпочесть жаву дотнету

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что когда явно известно что на входе массив, компилятор может позволить себе оптимизацию и сгенерировать код, который просто будет обращаться по индексу, что очень быстро. В случае же с `IEnumerable` приходится действовать как положено — с созданием итератора, вызовом его методов и т.д., что дает дополнительную константу в O(n), которую ваш тест и показал.

Для сравнения, код на выходе примерно соответствует такому:

```
public int SumArray(int[] numbers)
{
    int num = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    while (num2 < numbers.Length)
    {
        int num3 = numbers[num2];
        num += num3;
        num2++;
    }
    return num;
}

public int SumIEnumerable(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    int num = 0;
    IEnumerator<int> enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int current = enumerator.Current;
            num += current;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumerator != null)
        {
            enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

<sub>Подсмотрено [здесь](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAFgNwFgBQWoGYEBMcAwnAN5ZZzUL4CWAdgC5wDKArgLYCCATrwEMAngApGTANoBdOAy4AjAKa8AzgEoqNCphq644uCq5wAvHBgYde6gDMA9r0UCAxgAs4Y5rP0NZC5eqa1rpGnHBgZgyWwQgA7IZc0TQAvpRW1Hg+LBycSLgieQA84gB8fpxKqhrp5EF6BqGm5knW9o4u7p4svozllYE1MY0Rsi16UPGhY6mYyUA)</sub>