# c# ConcurrentDictionary to IReadOnlyList

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, linq, словари

У меня есть ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Foo> _dic = new();

Класс Foo внутри себя имеет несколько полей. Мне нужно только одно поле.

В плане реализации - можно использовать _dic.Values.Select(x => x.needProperty).ToList(), НО сама property Values под капотом создаёт новый List. Как-нибудь можно без двойного преобразования к List получить лист нужных property из класса Foo? Нужно получить только одно конкретное поле needProperty.

С помощью каста тоже не получится, т.к. IEnumerable к IReadOnlyList не кастится ((IReadOnlyCollection)_dic.Values.Select(x => x.needProperty) - будет ошибка)

https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Where.SpeedOpt.cs,6e33b46aba3510c8
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробегитесь в цикле по словарю и отфильтруйте. Заодно и лишнего лока не будет.

Comment: @vitidev его и так не будет, если брать его собственный энумератор, а не коллекцию значений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас разработка под .NET Framework 4.x? Если нет, то вы не в те исходники смотрите. Для .NET 6 исходники можно посмотреть [тут](https://source.dot.net/) или [тут](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime).

```
_dic.Select(x => x.Value.needProperty).ToArray()
```

Не используйте списки там где не требуется модификация коллекции после создания. Дополнительно убедитесь в том, что словарь не изменяется из другого потока во время чтения, а то может получиться так, что пока вы его читаете, либо успеете подхватить изменения, либо нет, как повезет.

В плане потокобезопасности, лучше использовать `_dic.Values`, оно снимет снапшот словаря на момент запроса, залочив его при формировании списка.

Comment: Этот список нужно только для чтения, поэтому он как раз таки ReadOnly.

Comment: Разве использование ToArray() не создаёт под капотом ещё одного массива/коллекции? Я как раз таки хочу избежать двойного создания. Есть уже идея - создать ещё одну коллекцию, в которую добавлять тот же элемент, но уже конкретно needProperty (с таким же guid). Что-то вроде ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, needProperty>. И Tryremove из обоих словарей сразу. Конечно, выглядит это не очень, т.к. уже 2 поля используются, но вариантов другой реализации пока что не вижу

Comment: @Frehzy создает, точно так же как ToList() создает список, но массив создается быстрее и легче списка. Я вам показал, как исправить Linq запрос, чтобы было только одно создание, вы только ToArray увидели чтоли? Посмотрите в мой код еще раз, внимательнее.

Comment: Да, разобрался. Покопался в документации и всё встало на свои места. Спасибо

Comment: Я вот заглянул сейчас в код - удивительно, почему array работает быстрее. Ведь по факту, они всё равно сходятся по итогу к одному и тому же

Comment: @Frehzy потому что `List`, это обертка над массивом. А каждая обертка - это дополнительный код. Плюс [вот это еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1306276/373567).

Comment: Теперь совершенно всё встало на свои места. Спасибо, ещё раз