# Необходимо увеличить скорость поиска больших простых чисел через сито Эратосфена

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Данные код имеет оптимизацию по памяти. Так это сито сегментированное. Мне нужна оптимизация по времени.

WinForm

```
        void simpleSieve(ulong limit, ArrayList prime)
        {

            bool[] mark = new bool[limit + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < mark.Length; i++)
                mark[i] = true;

            for (ulong p = 2; p * p < limit; p++)

            {

                if (mark[p] == true)
                {

                    for (ulong i = (ulong)(p * p); i < limit; i += (ulong)p)
                        mark[i] = false;
                }
            }


            for (ulong p = 2; p < limit; p++)

            {
                if (mark[p] == true)
                {
                    prime.Add(p);
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(p + " ");

                }
            }
        }

        void segmentedSieve(ulong n)
        {

            int limit = (int)(Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)) + 1);
            ArrayList prime = new ArrayList();
            simpleSieve((ulong)limit, prime);


            ulong low = (ulong)limit;
            ulong high = (ulong)(2 * limit);


            while (low < n)
            {
                if (high >= n)
                    high = n;


                bool[] mark = new bool[limit + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i < mark.Length; i++)
                    mark[i] = true;


                for (int i = 0; i < prime.Count; i++)
                {

                    ulong loLim = ((ulong)Math.Floor((double)(low / (ulong)prime[i])) * (ulong)prime[i]);
                    if (loLim < low)
                        loLim += (ulong)prime[i];


                    for (ulong j = loLim; j < high; j += (ulong)prime[i])
                        mark[j - low] = false;
                }


                for (ulong i = low; i < high; i++)
                    if (mark[i - low] == true)
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(i + " ");
                low = low + (ulong)limit;
                high = high + (ulong)limit;
            }
        }
```

Console

```
 static void simpleSieve(int limit,
                        ArrayList prime)
{
    /
    bool[] mark = new bool[limit + 1];
     
    for (int i = 0; i < mark.Length; i++)
        mark[i] = true;
 
    for (int p = 2; p * p < limit; p++)
    {
       
        if (mark[p] == true)
        {
            
            for (int i = p * p; i < limit; i += p)
                mark[i] = false;
        }
    }
 
   
    for (int p = 2; p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (mark[p] == true)
        {
            prime.Add(p);
            Console.Write(p + " ");
        }
    }
}
 

static void segmentedSieve(int n)
{
    
    int limit = (int) (Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)) + 1);
    ArrayList prime = new ArrayList();
    simpleSieve(limit, prime);
 
    
    int low = limit;
    int high = 2*limit;
 
    
    while (low < n)
    {
        if (high >= n)
            high = n;

        
        bool[] mark = new bool[limit + 1];
         
        for (int i = 0; i < mark.Length; i++)
            mark[i] = true;
 
        
        // primes in current range
        for (int i = 0; i < prime.Count; i++)
        {
            
            int loLim = ((int)Math.Floor((double)(low /
                        (int)prime[i])) * (int)prime[i]);
            if (loLim < low)
                loLim += (int)prime[i];
 
            
            for (int j = loLim; j < high; j += (int)prime[i])
                mark[j-low] = false;
        }
 
        
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++)
            if (mark[i - low] == true)
                Console.Write(i + " ");
 
        
        low = low + limit;
        high = high + limit;
    }
}
 

static void Main()
{
    int n = 100;
    Console.WriteLine("Primes smaller than " + n + ":");
    segmentedSieve(n);
}
```

Comment: иногда нужно не алгоритм оптимизировать, а использовать более быстрые алгоритмы.

Comment: `оптимизация по времени` - сколько сейчас и сколько надо? Как тестируете?

Comment: Необходимо использовать именно сито Эратосфена@KoVadim

Comment: Можете переписать код для консоли с предустановленными значениями, чтобы можно было хотя-бы профайлером пройтись. Сейчас код выдран из приложения и не может быть запущен. Укажите критерии успеха оптимизации.

Comment: Сейчас временная сложность O(n log log n). Необходимо чтобы было O(n).@aepot

Comment: @kamaha дело не только в асимптитике, как это запустить и проверить? Что вводить в текстбокс? Ок, я сам переписал для консоли, а чему у вас равняется N?

Comment: @aepot добавил код консоли

Comment: @ N вводится с клавиатуры

Comment: Ну, для 100 у меня мгновенно отрабатывает, зачему тут что-либо оптимизировать?

Comment: Необходимо до 1000000000 @aepot

Comment: Алгоритм с линейным временем требует памяти под n целых чисел. Многовато будет для указанного лимита

Comment: @MBo Вот мне и нужно сублинейное время O(n).

Comment: O(n) - это линейное время, никакого сублинейного быть не может просто по сути задачи заполнения n элементов. 4 гигабайта памяти сможете выделить под таблицу?

Comment: У меня около 10 секунд считает для 1000000000. Это долго?

Comment: я думаю, что можно один раз посчитать, сохранить в файл. И готово. А когда то я уже здесь писал, как упаковать очень компактно такое.

Comment: @aepot это шикарно!! Можешь показать код

Comment: Покажу, пока не закончил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понизить асимптотическую сложность данного алгоритма без ущерба потреблению памяти практически невозможно.

Но здесь можно сделать следующие вещи:

- Уменьшить количество генерируемого мусора, это позволит сборщику реже останавливтаь код для сборки, следовательно увеличит производительность кода.
- Данные, используемые часто разместить в массиве, а не в списке для блоее быстрого к ним доступа.
- Избавиться от вывода на экран во время расчетов, результатом работы метода считать наполненную коллекцию простых чисел, смысл выводить на экран 50847534 чисел, верно? Вы же никогда не сможете визуально проверить каждое.
- Избавиться от лишних приведений типов, если это не повлияет на результат работы. `long.MaxValue` - вполне достаточно для задания интервала поиска. Если вы зададите это число, считать будет очень долго, поэтому увеличение его в 2 раза за счет `ulong` не считаю полезным.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<long> result = SegmentedSieve(1000000000);
    Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed = {sw.Elapsed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Total numbers = {result.Count}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void SimpleSieve(int limit, List<long> prime)
{
    bool[] mark = new bool[limit];

    for (int p = 2; p * p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (!mark[p])
        {
            for (int i = p * p; i < limit; i += p)
                mark[i] = true;
        }
    }

    for (int p = 2; p < limit; p++)
    {
        if (!mark[p])
            prime.Add(p);
    }
}

static List<long> SegmentedSieve(long n)
{
    int limit = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(n));
    List<long> result = new(limit);
    SimpleSieve(limit, result);
    long[] prime = result.ToArray();

    long low = limit;
    long high = 2 * limit;
    bool[] mark = new bool[limit];

    while (low < n)
    {
        if (high >= n)
            high = n;

        foreach (long p in prime)
        {
            long loLim = low / p * p;
            if (loLim < low)
                loLim += p;

            for (long j = loLim; j < high; j += p)
                mark[j - low] = true;
        }

        for (long i = low; i < high; i++)
            if (!mark[i - low])
                result.Add(i);

        low += limit;
        high += limit;
        Array.Fill(mark, false);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Вывод в консоль Debug сборки

```
Elapsed = 00:00:08.8822729
Total numbers = 50847534
```

Вывод в консоль Release сборки

```
Elapsed = 00:00:03.3784039
Total numbers = 50847534
```

3,4 секунды - думаю, неплохо

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Буду дома проверю как работает @aepot

Comment: capacity в конструкторе списка вроде как за размер внутреннего массива и отвечает, поэтому не должно быть разницы массив prime или список result

Comment: @Grundy есть разница при обращении по индексу. При работе с массивом выполняется просто адресация в памяти, при работе со списком вызывается геттер индексатора, который очевидно работает медленнее, чем просто прямое обращение к памяти. Я здесь задаю capacity только для того чтобы избежать лишнего мусора на ранних стадиях работы алгоритма, список по умолчанию имеет размер 16 элементов и далее удваивает внутренний массив при добавлении элементов. Закидывая туда побольше при создании списка, я избегаю лишних аллокаций.

Comment: @aepot, хотелось бы тестов

Comment: @Grundy https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306279/373567, но с индексаторами ровно та же история, что и с перечислителем.

Comment: @aepot, честно говоря есть сомнения, что будет отличаться, учитывая JIT

Comment: @Grundy просто заменить тип `long[] prime` на `List<long>`, в дебаге теряю 1 секунду, в релизе в рамках статистической погрешности, сейчас попробую пооптимизировать, если вы правы, обновлю ответ, так как клонирование данных хоть и разовое - штука не полезная. Спасибо.

Comment: @aepot, в отладчике - понятно, что хуже будет, а вот в релизе интересно.

Comment: @Grundy странно, но избавившись от массива и работая с исходным списком, в релизе стало только хуже примерно на ~0.4сек, то есть на 10%. Пробовал и перечислитель и индексатор, перечислитель незначительно медленнее. Так что пока код из ответа можно считать что лучший из всех что я получил. Можно конечно SIMD/unsafe/потоков накрутить, но это уже другой уровень оптимизаций.