# когда использовать потокобезопасные конструкции в PLINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, tpl, plinq

Приведу три примера выборки из коллекций с использованием PlINQ.
1 Пример

```
//List<MDRItem> startMdrItems, List<SDSItem> sdsItemsGlobal это коллекции кастомных классов
//передаются в метод в качестве параметров
 var mdrFiltered = (from mdrItem in startMdrItems.AsParallel()
                               from sdsItem in sdsItemsGlobal.AsParallel()
                               where mdrItem.TitleNumber == sdsItem.TitleNumber && sdsItem.TitleStatus == "Активный"
                               select mdrItem
                              ).ToList();
```

2 пример

```
//List<TSRItem> tsrFiltered, List<SDSItem> sdsItems это коллекции кастомных классов

var tsrFilteredSecond = (from tsrItem in tsrFiltered.AsParallel()
                                     from sdsItem in sdsItems.AsParallel()
                                     where tsrItem.TitleNumber == sdsItem.TitleNumber && sdsItem.TitleStatus == "Активный"
                                     select new TSRItem()
                                     {

                                         RowIdx = tsrItem.RowIdx,
                                         FileName = tsrItem.FileName,
                                         ProjectFromSchedule = tsrItem.ProjectFromSchedule,
                                         ProjectName = tsrItem.ProjectName,
                                         GosFinSign = sdsItem.GosFinSign
                                     }
                                    );
```

3 пример

```
//List<TSRItem> tsrFilteredSecond коллекция кастомного класса
var listToForeach = new ConcurrentBag<TSRItem>(tsrFilteredSecond);
ConcurrentBag<TSRItem> filterdTsrItems = new ConcurrentBag<TSRItem>();
listToForeach.AsParallel().ForAll/*.ForEach*/(tsr =>
            {
                var chekedTitleNumber = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tsr.TitleNumber) ? "" : tsr.TitleNumber;
                var chekedMark = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tsr.Mark) ? "" : string.Concat(":", tsr.Mark);

                tsr.MarkSMGenerated = GenerateMarkSM(tsr.PurchaseSpecification);
                var checkedMarkSm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tsr.MarkSMGenerated) ? "" : string.Concat(":", tsr.MarkSMGenerated);

                tsr.NomenclatureGroupMTOGenerated = GenerateGroupMTO(tsr);
                var checkedNomenclatureGroupMTOGenerated = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tsr.NomenclatureGroupMTOGenerated) ? "" : string.Concat(":", tsr.NomenclatureGroupMTOGenerated);

                tsr.BuildingcodeGenerated = GenerateBulidingCode(tsr);
                var checkedBuildingCode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tsr.BuildingcodeGenerated) ? "" : string.Concat(":", tsr.BuildingcodeGenerated);

                tsr.GeneratedKey = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", chekedTitleNumber, chekedMark, checkedMarkSm, checkedBuildingCode, checkedNomenclatureGroupMTOGenerated);


                filterdTsrItems.Add(tsr);

            });
```

Вопрос следующий:
Нужно ли при выполнении таких переборов объявлять потокобезопасные коллекции(например использовать ConcurrentBag вместо List как в 3 м примере)?
Т.е.  для первого примера использовать ConcurrentBag  startMdrItems, ConcurrentBag  sdsItemsGlobal, для второго ConcurrentBag  tsrFiltered, ConcurrentBag  sdsItems.
Выявил проблему с потокобезопасностостью в 3 примере в строчке filterdTsrItems.Add(tsr); когда filterdTsrItems был объявлен через List<> а не через ConcurrentBag<>, отсюда и возникли сомнения по поводу остальных примеров.

Comment: По поводу закомментированного `ForEach`: [Prefer ForAll to ForEach when it is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-with-plinq#prefer-forall-to-foreach-when-it-is-possible). `ForAll` в данном случае действительно лучше. Но только при использовании потокобезопасной коллекции внутри! А если взять `ForEach`, то коллекциию можно использовать любую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При наличии чтения и отсутствии записи совершенно безопасно иметь доступ к коллекции из нескольких потоков. Познакомьтесь с концепцией Reader/Writer Lock. Она говорит о том, что писать может только один, а читать могут сколько угодно потоков, но только пока никто не пишет.

- Первый пример - запись в `mdrFiltered` происходит в одном потоке, всё ок
- Второй пример - `tsrFilteredSecond` это не материализованный запрос, а перечислитель, запрос выполнится позже
- Третий пример - `filterdTsrItems` ок как потокобезопасная коллекция, `listToForeach` не ок, так как эта коллекция только для чтения и для нее не требуется какая-либо потокобезопасность

Совет: используйте массивы вместо списков там, где не надо модифицировать состав коллекции, это полезно для производительности кода [в некоторых случаях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1306276/373567). Если нужно для потокобезопасности снять снапшот с какого-то непотокобезопасного источника данных в многопоточной среде, спокойно используйте `.ToArray()` на источнике данных под локом в случае если возможна конкурентная запись. Если же запись в коллекцию во время ее перечисления невозможна, можно спокойно обойтись без снапшотов и перечислять её саму.

Comment: Уточняющий вопрос: по 3 примеру: при переборе listToForeach я записываю свойства каждого экземпляра tsr (например  tsr.GeneratedKey=....), разве здесь нет записи

Comment: @AntonovKonstantin но ведь не к списку обращаетесь, а к членам его элемента. Сам список при этом только читается.

Comment: и по второму примеру если запрос будет выглядеть var tsrFilteredSecond =(... все тоже самое).ToArray() или .ToList()?

Comment: @AntonovKonstantin `.ToArray()` и `.ToList()` в плане потокобезопасности не отличаются ничем.