# Почему Parallel.ForEach работает медленее со списком строк чем foreach?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть код для поиска слов в списке, начинающихся с введённых символов с использованием foreach и Parallel.ForEach. При этом при использовании обычного foreach поиск выполняется быстрее. В чём может быть причина? Может ли это быть связано с накладыванием дополнительных расходов ресурсов и времени на организацию параллельных потоков?

```
foreach (var word in words)
{
     if (word.StartsWith(searchString))
        {
            matchingWords.Add(word);
        }
 }
```

И Parallel.ForEach

```
   Parallel.ForEach(words, word =>
   {
       if (word.StartsWith("b"))
         {
           lock (matchingWords)
           {
              matchingWords.Add(word);
           }
         }
   });
```

Comment: [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies). Использование разделения (partition) выгодно в случае маленького объёма работы на каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: не знаю, может поэтому неверный вывод у автора... в версии с Parallel.ForEach делается сверка с "b", а не с searchString. в моих измерениях параллельный алгоритм показал трехкратное увеличение скорости (.NET 4.8) и минимальное увеличение скорости (.NET 7) на моем 4-ядерном процессоре. значит накладные расходы есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, это связано с дополнительными расходами на организацию многопоточки. А кроются эти расходы в том что итерация такого цикла выполняется значительно быстрее, чем даже извлечение запущенного потока из пула потоков, не говоря уж о запуске нового потока.

Плюс к вышесказанному тормозов добавляет `lock`, так как подмораживает каждую из итераций, ради того чтобы не повредить результирующую коллекуцию. Как вариант, можно использовать потокобезопасную коллекцию, типа `ConcurrentBag<T>`.

Если вам хочется вывести вычисления в отдельный поток. Сделайте просто так.

```
Task<List<string>> task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    List<string> result = new();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        if (word.StartsWith(searchString))
        {
            result.Add(word);
        }
    }
    return result;
});
// здесь можно нарисовать в интерфейсе, что поиск начался
List<string> filteredWords = await task;
// здесь можно отобразить результат
```

И `lock` в таком случае не потребуется.

Кстати, если так важна производительность, то `foreach` по массиву [работает быстрее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1306276/373567), чем по списку.

Comment: ваш пример полностью идентичен простой версии (т.е. выполняется в один поток). опубликовал измерения в своем ответе

Comment: @АлексейОбухов несовсем, вычисления выведены в отдельный поток, а это значит, например для UI приложения, что UI не подмерзнет на время выполнения. Такие быстрые CPU-bound вычисления лучше всего параллелятся через SIMD, но об этом вопроса не было. Вопрос был "почему медленнее?", я ответил. Код - это лишь дополнение к вариантам решения потенциальной проблемы замораживания приложения во время длительной работы этого кода.

Comment: тем не менее изначальное предположение, что многопоточная версия медленнее однопоточной неверна. даже с учетом возможный накладных расходов на lock. можно и без него написать.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов ваш ответ правильный, но попытка сравнить производительность моего и вашего или исходного вариантов - бессмысленна. Вы же это понимаете? Само собой, что синхронный цикл **никогда не будет быстрее, чем он сам**.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов здесь можно устроить SIMD, разбить коллекцию на чанки, еще можно много всего сделать, чтобы `Parallel.ForEach` глотал пыль по производительности. Но еще раз, вопрос был не об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Update: поступили замечания по тесту. Мои комментарии:

1. Сборка в релизе не дает никакой прибавки к скорости
2. Убирание lock (он тут не нужен) дает минимальную прибавку к скорости
3. .NET 7 на тесте работает на порядок медленнее, чем .NET 4.8

---

Написал свой тест, который показал, что ваше предположение о медленной работе в несколько потоков неверно. Результаты работы программы опубликованной ниже:

simple: 00:00:04.2730974, parallel: 00:00:01.6736944, aepot: 00:00:04.3022718

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var swSimple = new Stopwatch();
            var swParallel = new Stopwatch();
            var swAepot = new Stopwatch();
            var random = new Random();
            string searchString = new string('0', 100);
            var words = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5e3; i++)
            {
                char randomNum = "0123456789"[random.Next(10)];
                string sampleString = new string(randomNum, random.Next(100 * i));
                words.Add(sampleString);

                swSimple.Start();
                var list1 = RunSimple(words, searchString);
                swSimple.Stop();

                swParallel.Start();
                var list2 = RunParallel(words, searchString);
                swParallel.Stop();

                swAepot.Start();
                var list3 = RunAepot(words, searchString);
                swAepot.Stop();

                if (list1.Count != list2.Count || list3.Count != list1.Count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Функции не идентичны: words={words.Count}, searchString={searchString.Length}, RunSimple: {list1.Count}, RunParallel: {list2.Count}, RunAepot: {list3.Count}");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"simple: {swSimple.Elapsed}, parallel: {swParallel.Elapsed}, aepot: {swAepot.Elapsed}");

        }

        static List<string> RunSimple(List<string> words, string searchString)
        {
            var matchingWords = new List<string>();
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                if (word.StartsWith(searchString))
                {
                    matchingWords.Add(word);
                }
            }
            return matchingWords;
        }

        static List<string> RunParallel(List<string> words, string searchString)
        {
            var matchingWords = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
            Parallel.ForEach(words, word =>
            {
                if (word.StartsWith(searchString))
                {
                    lock (matchingWords)
                    {
                        matchingWords.Add(word);
                    }
                }
            });
            return matchingWords.ToList();
        }

        static List<string> RunAepot(List<string> words, string searchString)
        {
            Task<List<string>> task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<string> result = new List<string>();
                foreach (var word in words)
                {
                    if (word.StartsWith(searchString))
                    {
                        result.Add(word);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            });
            // здесь можно нарисовать в интерфейсе, что поиск начался
            //List<string> filteredWords = await task;
            // здесь можно отобразить результат
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `task.Wait();` или `task.Result;` полностью ломает смысл кода в моем ответе и является грубой ошибкой при использовании асинхронных методов, таких как `Task.Run`.

Comment: ну тут распараллеливание по поиску в массиве, а не распараллеливание по всем поискам

Comment: Я и не предлагал никакого распараллеливания, для того чтобы это предлагать, надо было знать проблему. Я лишь ответил на вопрос "почему медленнее". Хотя про `lock` тоже следовало добавить, сейчас допишу.

Comment: Замеры в релизе кстати сделайте, а не в дебаге. Здесь не все так гладко. И желательно несколько итераций измерений на коллекциях разного размера.

Comment: `ConcurrentBag` потокобезопасный, не нужно лочить его метод `Add`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov lock очень быстрый, см. дополнение к ответу

Comment: @aepot дополнил ответ, релизная сборка, как ни странно, на скорость не влияет. тест и так делает прогоны в большом кол-ве по строкам и массивам разного размера, не вижу надобности в его переделке. тест скорее для демонстрации, что Parallel.ForEach реально ускоряет работу (что логично). понятно, что любой тест будет показывать то, что удобно тестировщику.

Comment: _.NET 7 на тесте работает на порядок медленнее, чем .NET 4.8_ это невозможно по той простой причине, что должно быть в точности наоборот. _Сборка в релизе не дает никакой прибавки к скорости_ - Вы не смогли собрать релизную сборку (галочка "оптимизировать код").

Comment: Ну и работа через `lock` с потокобезопасной коллекцией - пустая трата времени. То есть все 3 тезиса мимо.

Comment: На .NET7 действительно какая-то чертовщина творится с этим кодом: выполняется несколько минут, а на FW4.8 несколько секунд. Даже интересно стало. Нужно профилировать. @aepot

Comment: @aepot галочка "Optimize code" стоит. как я понимаю, оптимизатор в c# работает и действительно в некоторых случаях дает кратную прибавку к скорости, но часто просто бесполезен. вот тут есть какие-то [обсуждения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444467/benefits-of-optimize-code-option-in-visual-studio-build)

Comment: @АлексейОбухов вы ссылаетесь на обсуждение 12-летней давности, оно неактуально.

Comment: @aepot ну почему же не актуально? .NET 4 вышел 2010 году, как раз 12 лет прошло. хотя конечно обсуждения на каком-то форуме не могут быть приняты за истину. лично я для себя отметил конструкцию Parallel.ForEach как перспективную. вполне возможно что вы правы, она не всегда ускоряет работу (в [статье](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies) от Alexander Petrov говорится, что маленькое тело внутри Parallel.ForEach делать невыгодно, хотя мой тест это не подтверждает)

Comment: @АлексейОбухов у `Parallel.*` есть один огромный недостаток - он блокирует вызывающий поток, поэтому [как-то так приходится выкручиваться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567). Для меня это API выглядит устаревшим и неюзабельным.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, попробовал запустить Ваш код у себя на .NET 4.8. И получил совершенно другие результаты:

simple: 00:00:07.6115842, parallel: 00:00:20.4587524, aepot: 00:00:08.1802551

Comment: @heavenbeyond91 предполагаю, что тут зависимость от процессора (100% нагрузка на него). указанный мной результат получен на i5-8562u, на процессоре i7-3770k результаты чуть похуже (примерно такие же, по количеству потоков и ядер они одинаковые). также тест при работе требует около 1ГБ памяти.